# Spring @Async. XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I need to configure one asynchronous method in my project. I trying to it it this way:

This is my spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
            "
        >
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <task:executor id="asyncExecutor" pool-size="5" />
    <task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" />
```

and the method:

```
@Async
public Future<Boolean> async() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
    return new AsyncResult<>(true);
}
```

When I run test, I get an Exception:

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
```

If I delete `<task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" />` then method doesn't start asynchronously.

What wrong with my config?